# select data conversion based on value range

Tags: awk, files, math

I have a text file with 3 columns of data. However at random times in the various files there is a change in the in the observed unit from ppn to ppb resulting in the need of a conversion factor and multiplication by 1000.

```
actual data                        needed data look
20101001,01:00,0.3                 20101001,01:00,0.3,300.000
20110103,10:00,212.67              20110103,10:00,212.670,212.670
```

I have a awk command to print all original and add a fourth column with the conversion.

The only issue is it prints everything everything in the third column by 1000 and print to the fourth column. The command is below....

```
awk -F ',' '{printf "%s %s %.3f %.3f\n", $1,$2,$3,$3*1000}' temp7.tmp > County001-CO-0012.out
```

How can I can only values between 2 and -1 in column #3 only get multiplied by 1000 and other wise print the orignal value of column 3 in column 4?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in the awk code:

```c
{
    # if $3 is between -1 and 2, multiply by 1000
    converted = $3 * (-1 <= $3 && $3 <= 2 ? 1000 : 1)
    printf "%s %s %.3f %.3f\n", $1, $2, $3, converted
}
```